# Set different header path in c++ in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, header, setup-project

I have a very big c++ project that I am trying to view through eclipse. There are multiple header inclusions like this:

```
#include <SampleName/headerfile.hpp>
```

But the header file's path is in ../SampleName/export/headerfile.hpp.
Somehow during compilation the path SampleName/export is set to SampleName but this causes multiple Unresolved inclusions in eclipse

I have tried adding the SampleName/export folder in all tabs in Project->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols but with no effect.
Any ideas?

Comment: You have to add the additional include path in your project's build option settings.

Comment: @user0042 can you share how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project in the project viewer and from the drop-down menu select "Properties".

Then select `"C/C++ General"` -> `"Prepoessor include paths.."`

Make sure the `"Entries"` tab is selected and select `C++` in the `"Languages"` list.

Then select `"CDT User Setting Entries"` and click on the `"Add"` button.

[image]